# Appending a None value in a try except block

Tags: python

I am wondering whether if it's possible to append a `None` into a dictionary if an attribute is missing.
Here I have created a somewhat of a similar problem I am having using a dictionary.
In this example, the dictionary has some missing key and value pair (in this case Country Ecuador is missing the area info and the country Spain is missing the continent info).

I want to create a new dictionary with the missing keys and values included (The value will be `None`). So in other words the new dictionary will contain an area field with None for the country Ecuador and a continent field with None value for Spain.

```
country_info =[{'Country' : 'Sri Lanka', 'Continent' : 'Asia', 'Area' :  65610}, {'Country': 'Ecuador', 'Continent':'South America'}, {'Country' : 'Botswana', 'Continent' : 'Africa', 'Area' : 581730}, {'Country' : 'Vietnam', 'Continent' : 'Asia', 'Area' : 331212}, {'Country' : 'Spain', 'Area' : 505990 }]
```

country_info

```
new_list = []
for i in country_info:
    try:
        new_list.append({
            'country' : i['Country'],
            'continent' : i['Continent'],
            'area' : i['Area']
        })
    except KeyError:
        None
```

The code above recreates the same original dictionary. What I am wishing for is...

output:

```
country_info =[{'Country' : 'Sri Lanka', 'Continent' : 'Asia', 'Area' :  65610}, {'Country': 'Ecuador', 'Continent':'South America', 'Area' : None}, {'Country' : 'Botswana', 'Continent' : 'Africa', 'Area' : 581730}, {'Country' : 'Vietnam', 'Continent' : 'Asia', 'Area' : 331212}, {'Country' : 'Spain', 'Continent' : None, 'Area' : 505990 }]
```

Comment: use `dict.get()` method to access the elements. by default it will return None

Comment: Can you make the lists readable instead of forcing to scroll?

Comment: If you wish for title case, why do you force lower case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want failed lookups to produce `None`, use [the `dict.get` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead of square bracketed lookup and avoid the `KeyError` entirely:

```
new_list = []
for i in country_info:
    new_list.append({
        'country' : i.get('Country'),
        'continent' : i.get('Continent'),
        'area' : i.get('Area')
    })
```

The problem with catching the `KeyError` is that you skip *all* the `append` related code when it happens, and it's annoying (though not impossible) to properly determine which key was missing. Since `get` is effectively an expression-by-expression "catch `KeyError`, replace with `default` (which itself defaults to `None`)", it's a lot more convenient here.

Comment: Correcting my answer would lead to this answer. so deleted mine. Thanks all for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default value for a key if it does not exist.
Simply do

```
...
'area':i.get('Area',None)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more ways:

```
new_list = [
    {'Country': None, 'Continent': None, 'Area': None, **i}
    for i in country_info
]
```

```
new_list = []
for i in country_info:
    info = dict.fromkeys(('Country', 'Continent', 'Area'))
    info.update(i)
    new_list.append(info)
```